# Nested for loop to create summary table of mean and SD in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of shape (2,2,1000) representing income-groups, age-groups and a sample of 1000 observations for each group.

I am trying to use a for-loop to calculate a summary table.

I would like to receive a table of the following sort:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

elasticity = np.random.rand(2,2,1000)
print(elasticity.shape)

income = ['i0','i1']
age_gr= ['<=18','>18']

data=[]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(age_gr)):
    row=[]
    for j in range((len(income))):
        row.append(np.mean(elasticity[i,j,:]))
        row.append(np.std(elasticity[i,j,:]))
        data.append(row)
data

df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df
```

But there is something wrong with my for-loop and I keep getting 4x4 table of the mean and standard deviation instead of the 2x4 that I would like. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.append(row)` is inside the `for j` loop instead of the `for i` loop.

Just un-tab it once:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

elasticity = np.random.rand(2,2,1000)
print(elasticity.shape)

income = ['i0','i1']
age_gr= ['<=18','>18']

data=[]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(age_gr)):
    row=[]
    for j in range((len(income))):
        row.append(np.mean(elasticity[i,j,:]))
        row.append(np.std(elasticity[i,j,:]))
    data.append(row)  # **************************** <=
data

df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the location of `row = []`.

What your row currently looks like over the loop is:

```
i = 0, j = 0:
[] -> [ value1 , value2 ]
i = 0, j = 1:
[ value1 , value2 ] -> [ value1 , value2, value3, value4 ]

i = 1, j = 0:
[] -> [ value1 , value2 ]
i = 1, j = 1:
[ value1 , value2 ] -> [ value1 , value2, value3, value4 ]
```

The solution should simply be to move the `row = []` into the second `for`-loop. That way you will append `data` with 2-item lists 4 times instead of the previous solution.